# Good SQL search tool?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

FreeTextTable is really great for searching, as it actually returns a relevancy score for each item it finds.

The problem is, it doesn't support the logical operator AND, so if I have 10 items with the word 'ice' in it, but not 'cream', and vice versa, then 20 results will be returned, when in this scenario 0 should've been returned.

Are there any alternative tools to search a SQL Server database? Or should I just write my own code to provide 'AND' functionality (I.E. doing two seperate searches in the scenario 'Ice'Cream' (splitting each search by spaces))

Comment: Have you looked into CONTAINSTABLE instead of FREETEXTTABLE? That supports boolean operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/) from RedGate.

It is a free tool (though not open source) - I have used it before and it is very powerful.

Comment: Actually, it **IS** a **FREE** tool - and quite useful indeed !

Comment: I believe maxp is asking for a tool to search the DATA of his database, SQL Search looks at the SCHEMA items (Table names, column names etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a free SQL Search tool from ApexSQL you can try. It integrates into SSMS and can also show relationship diagrams and help with safely removing/renaming objects in your database. They do require you to leave email but the product itself is completely free. [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx)

Comment: sadly, no longer free
https://blog.apexsql.com/what-happened-to-the-apexsql-free-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have full text search enabled to use FREETEXTTABLE perhaps you could make use of CONTAINS instead? (I have to be honest, I've not used full text search myself).

It would appear you can query like this:

```
SELECT Name, Price FROM Product
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, 'ice')
 AND CONTAINS(Name, 'cream')
```